# Mysql - Delete All except 2 rows of all post_id1 from a table

Tags: mysql

I have one table ABC which has 1 milion+ rows :

```
post_id1    post_id2    count
    22      100218      1
    22      100225      2
    22      100432      1
    22      100719      5
    22      100807      4
    22      100827      3
    22      100934      22
    22      101322      1
    27      101613      10
    27      101931      1
    29      103783      1
    29      104328      16
    29      104345      1
    29      104356      7
```

In this table I just want to keep 2 rows of each post_id1 value (any two rows)

Like output will be

```
post_id1    post_id2    count
    22      100218      1
    22      100225      2
    27      101613      10
    27      101931      1
    29      103783      1
    29      104328      16
```

What SQL query should I run?

post_id1 can be any number.

Thanks

Comment: is ur post_id2 unique? or there is a chance for repeat?

Comment: post_id2 is unique in each post_id2. that is same post_id1 can not have same post_id2, that is not row is common.

Comment: yeah that's fine.Below solution(which i posted) didn't helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `postid_2` is unique as shown in the example. You can use the below query to delete.

```
delete from test
where post_id2 not in ( select post_id2
from (
      select post_id2 from test
      where (select count(*) from test as t where 
             t.post_id1=test.post_id1 and 
             t.post_id2>=test.post_id2)<=2) t);
```

Here i sorted based on post_id2(top 2 maximum will be displayed). You can check the [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1ee3/1) in SQLFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

You need user variables to store the number of rows each post_id1 returns. This query keeps track of the number of times post_id1 is found and stores it in the rows variable. Then it limits the output to where numRows <= 2.

```
SET @rows = NULL, @prevID = NULL;
SELECT post_id1, post_id2, count FROM (
    SELECT
       post_id, post_id2, count, 
       @rows := IF(@prevID = post_id1, @rows + 1, 1) AS numRows,
       @prevID := post_id1
FROM test 
) AS temp WHERE numRows <= 2
```

A link to the sqlfiddle for you to test the query yourself is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9635a/59).

Comment: I wanted to delete all rows of all post_id1 except 2 rows. Please tell how to delete from the table. The above command is listing the new table. I wanted a query which I can run in phpMyadmin. Sorry I'm a newbie.